# Strongly Type Entity Identifiers

Tags: c#

When working with service oriented applications we often use system types to identify / query our business entities.

```
IList<Product> GetProductsByUserAndCategoryId(int userId, int categoryId);
```

However we can't prevent developpers to pass another identifier which is not a "User Identifier" and not a "Category Identifier", or maybe inverse the ids on method call.

So a solution is to use Strongly Type Identifiers, like this :

```
IList<Product> GetProductsByUserAndCategoryId(UserId userId, CategoryId categoryId);

GetProductsByUserAndCategoryId(new UserId(123), new CategoryId(456));
```

What do you think about this ? Pros and cons ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pros and cons ?

Well, first off, this only shifts the moment of validation; it still has to happen, preferably as soon as a `UserId` (…) is instantiated. You also have to see whether this really has any benefits in your system at all.

On the other hand, I *do* think that it prevents bugs by disambiguating between inherently ambiguous numbers. Letting the same type `int` stand for two completely unrelated things *can* actually be dangerous.

In a recent code review (for a course at University) the no. 1 error students had made was to use an integer in the wrong way. Having used different types as in your example would effectively have prevented this source of errors altogether.

So, in summary, I don’t think there’s a blanked answer but **I am generally in favour of such idioms**. This is one of the real benefits of a strict type system.

Answer (score 1):

The only real con for me is having to type extra code.  You code becomes more tightly defined, which is a good thing, but now there is extra friction to actually getting it written.  It is just a matter of will spending the extra time and effort up front pay off in saved maintenance and dependability later.

It is the same with any methodology.  The TDD guys spend time building scaffolding and tests up front with the hope it will make there code more reliable and more easily maintainable.  -- Many of them say it saves time upfront as well...but I have my doubts :) --

Ultimately I agree with Mr. Rudolph.  This is the strength of strict type systems; Use it to your advantage.